# htaccess url rewriting script doesn't work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my website,when it is clicked "www.anketurkiye.com/ekonomianket", I want to my site to redirect to www.anketurkiye.com/ekonomibuton.php page. I have written the following script.However it doesn't run correctly. How can I solve this problem.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/ekonomianket$ ekonomibuton.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: define `it doesn't run correctly`

Answer (score 0):

Replace that `RewriteRule` line with this:

```
RewriteRule ^ekonomianket/?$ ekonomibuton.php [NC,L]
```

In your .htaccess leading slash is stripped off so you need to match without leading slash.